# New Div CSS not taking "top" and "left" types

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When appending a new div and changing the css values, the top and left values do not apply. Other values have no issue.

I temporarily used marginLeft and marginTop which seemed to work, but it is not as accurate as I would like it to be.

```
const createNewDiv = () => {
  for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.innerHTML = -i;
    document.getElementById("zero").appendChild(newDiv);
    $(newDiv).css({
      top: -i * 50,
      left: -3
    })
  }
}
```

I would like it to add 50px to the top for each div created.
Here is the application I'm using it for:

```js
let coordinates = [100, 200, 300, 400];
let x1 = document.getElementById("inputX1-1");
let x2 = document.getElementById("inputX2-3");
let y1 = document.getElementById("inputY1-2");
let y2 = document.getElementById("inputY2-4");

//Creates point A
const point1 = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
 let clicked = false;
 document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = "A (" + (x1 / 50) + ", " + (y1 / -50) + ")";
  $("#text1").css({
   visibility: "hidden"
  })
  $("#point1").mouseenter(function() {
   $("#text1").css({
     visibility: "visible"
    })
 })
  $("#point1").mouseleave(function() {
   $("#text1").css({
     visibility: "hidden"
    })
  })
  $("#point1").css({
   top: y1 + 260,
   left: x1 + 444.5
  })
  $("#text1").css({
   top: y1 + 240,
   left: x1 + 400.5
  })
}
//Creates point B
const point2 = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
 document.getElementById("text2").innerHTML = "B (" + (x2 / 50) + ", " + (y2 / -50) + ")";
  $("#text2").css({
   visibility: "hidden"
  })
  $("#point2").mouseenter(function() {
   $("#text2").css({
     visibility: "visible"
    })
  })
  $("#point2").mouseleave(function() {
   $("#text2").css({
     visibility: "hidden"
    })
  })
  $("#point2").css({
   top: y2 + 260,
   left: x2 + 444.5
  })
  $("#text2").css({
   top: y2 + 240,
   left: x2 + 400.5
  })
}
//Creates point C
const point3 = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
 document.getElementById("text3").innerHTML = "C (" + (x1 / 50) + ", " + (y2 / -50) + ")";
  $("#text3").css({
   visibility: "hidden"
  })
  $("#point3").mouseenter(function() {
   $("#text3").css({
     visibility: "visible"
    })
  })
  $("#point3").mouseleave(function() {
   $("#text3").css({
     visibility: "hidden"
    })
  })
  $("#point3").css({
   top: y2 + 260,
   left: x1 + 444.5
  })
  $("#text3").css({
   top: y2 + 240,
   left: x1 + 395.5
  })
}
//Creates line AC
const line1 = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => { //y values reversed due to -'ive input
  if (x1 < x2 && y1 < y2 || x1 > x2 && y1 < y2) {
    //(x1 < x2)&(y1 > y2) OR (x1 > x2)&(y1 > y2) for test (1 4 2 3) OR (2 4 1 3)
   $("#line1").css({
     top: y1 + 265
    })
  } else if (x1 < x2 && y1 > y2 || x1 > x2 && y1 > y2) {
    //(x1 < x2) & (y1 < y2) OR (x1 > x2)&(y1 < y2) for test (1 3 2 4) OR (2 3 1 4)
   $("#line1").css({
     top: y2 + 265
    })
  }
  $("#line1").css({
   height: Math.abs(y2 - y1),
   left: x1 + 449
  })
}
//Creates line BC
const line2 = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
 if (x1 < x2 && y1 < y2 || x1 < x2 && y1 > y2) {
   //(x1 < x2)&(y1 > y2) OR (x1 > x2)&(y1 < y2) for test (1 3 2 4) OR (1 4 2 3)
  $("#line2").css({
     left: x1 + 447.5
    })
  } else if (x1 > x2 && y1 < y2 || x1 > x2 && y1 > y2) {
   //(x1 > x2)&(y1 > y2) OR (x1 > x2)&(y1 < y2) for test (2 4 1 3) OR (2 3 1 4)
  $("#line2").css({
     left: x2 + 447.5
    })
  }
  $("#line2").css({
   width: Math.abs(x2 - x1),
   top: y2 + 264
  })
}
//Creates line AB
const line3  = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
 let a = y2 - y1;
  let b = x2 - x1;
 let c  = Math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b));
  if (x1 < x2 && y1 < y2 || x1 < x2 && y1 > y2) {
   //(x1 < x2)&(y1 > y2) OR (x1 < x2)&(y1 < y2) for test (1 4 2 3) (1 3 2 4)
   $("#line3").css({
     left: x1 + 450,
      top: y1 + 265
    })
  } else if (x1 > x2 && y1 < y2 || x1 > x2 && y1 > y2) {
   //(x1 > x2)&(y1 > y2) OR (x1 > x2)&(y1 < y2) for test (2 4 1 3) OR (2 3 1 4)
   $("#line3").css({
     left: x2 + 450,
     top: y2 + 265
   })
  }
  $("#line3").css({
   transform: "rotate(" + Math.atan(a / b) + "rad)",
   width: c
 })
}
//Creates text AC
const sine = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
 document.getElementById("sine").innerHTML = Math.abs((x2 - x1) / 50);
  if (x1 < x2 && y1 < y2) {
   //(x1 < x2)&(y1 > y2) for test (1 4 2 3)
  $("#sine").css({
     left: ((x2 - x1) / 2) - 2,
      top: 10
    })
  } else if (x1 < x2 && y1 > y2) {
   //(x1 < x2)&(y1 < y2) for test (1 3 2 4)
    $("#sine").css({
      left: ((x2 - x1) / 2) - 2,
      top: -23
    })
  } else if (x1 > x2 && y1 < y2) {
   //(x1 > x2)&(y1 > y2) for test (2 4 1 3)
    $("#sine").css({
     left: ((x1 - x2) / 2) - 2,
      top: 10
    })
  } else if (x1 > x2 && y1 > y2) {
   //(x1 > x2)&(y1 < y2) for test (2 3 1 4)
    $("#sine").css({
     left: ((x1 - x2) / 2) - 2,
      top: -23
    })
  }
}
//Creates text BC
const cosine = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
 document.getElementById("cosine").innerHTML = Math.abs((y2 - y1) / 50);
  if (x1 < x2 && y1 < y2) {
   //(x1 < x2)&(y1 > y2) for test (1 4 2 3)
   $("#cosine").css({
     left: -20,
      top: ((y2 - y1) / 2) - 7
    })
  } else if (x1 < x2 && y1 > y2) {
   //(x1 < x2)&(y1 < y2) for test (1 3 2 4)
    $("#cosine").css({
     left: -20,
      top: ((y1 - y2) / 2) - 7
    })
  } else if (x1 > x2 && y1 < y2) {
   //(x1 > x2)&(y1 > y2) for test (2 4 1 3)
    $("#cosine").css({
     left: 13,
      top: ((y2 - y1) / 2) - 7
    })
  } else if (x1 > x2 && y1 > y2) {
   //(x1 > x2)&(y1 < y2) for test (2 3 1 4)
    $("#cosine").css({
     left: 13,
      top: ((y1 - y2) / 2) - 7
    })
  }
}
//Creates text AB
const hypotenuse = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
 let a = (y2 - y1) / 50;
  let b = (x2 - x1) / 50;
  document.getElementById("hypotenuse").innerHTML = (Math.sqrt((a * a) + (b * b))).toFixed(1);
  if (x1 < x2 && y1 < y2) {
   //(x1 < x2)&(y1 > y2) for test (1 4 2 3)
    $("#hypotenuse").css({
     left: 460 + ((x1 + x2) / 2),
      top: 250 + ((y1 + y2) / 2)
    })
  } else if (x1 < x2 && y1 > y2) {
   //(x1 < x2)&(y1 < y2) for test (1 3 2 4)
    $("#hypotenuse").css({
     left: 460 + ((x1 + x2) / 2),
      top: 265 + ((y2 + y1) / 2)
    })
  } else if (x1 > x2 && y1 < y2) {
   //(x1 > x2)&(y1 > y2) for test (2 4 1 3)
    $("#hypotenuse").css({
     left: 460 + ((x2 + x1) / 2),
      top: 250 + ((y2 + y1) / 2)
    })
  } else if (x1 > x2 && y1 > y2) {
   //(x1 > x2)&(y1 < y2) for test (2 3 1 4)
    $("#hypotenuse").css({
     left: 460 + ((x2 + x1) / 2),
      top: 215 + ((y1 + y2) / 2)
    })
  }
}

const userInput = (x1, y1, x2, y2) => {
  point1(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  point2(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  point3(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  line1(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  line2(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  line3(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  sine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  cosine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  hypotenuse(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}

const createNewDiv = () => {
 for (let i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
   let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.innerHTML = -i;
    document.getElementById("zero").appendChild(newDiv);
    $(newDiv).css({
     top: i * 500,
      left: -3
   })
  }
}

$("#enter").click(function() {
  coordinates[0] = parseFloat(x1.value) * 50;
 coordinates[1] = parseFloat(y1.value) * -50;
 coordinates[2] = parseFloat(x2.value) * 50;
 coordinates[3] = parseFloat(y2.value) * -50;
  userInput(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2], coordinates[3]);
  $("#point1, #point2, #point3").show();
  $("#line1, #line2, #line3").show();
  $("#text1, #text2, #text3").show();
});

const onStart = () => {
 $("#point1, #point2, #point3").hide();
  $("#line1, #line2, #line3").hide();
  $("#text1, #text2, #text3").hide();
}

createNewDiv();
onStart();
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  height: 28px;
  left: 720px;
  width: 100px;
}

input {
  width: 50px;
}
p {
  height: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
}

#display {
  background: white;
  width: 900px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  border: 5px solid green;
}

#input {
  height: 30px;
  width: 900px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid green;
}

#gridY {
  left: 450px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #87b7d1;
  position: absolute;
}

#gridX {
  top: 250px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #87b7d1;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid1 {
  left: 25px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid2 {
  left: 50px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid3 {
  left: 75px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid4 {
  left: 100px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid5 {
  left: 125px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid6 {
  left: 150px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid7 {
  left: 175px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid8 {
  left: 200px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid9 {
  left: 225px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid10 {
  left: 250px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid11 {
  left: 275px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid12 {
  left: 300px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid13 {
  left: 325px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid14 {
  left: 350px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid15 {
  left: 375px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid16 {
  left: 400px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid17 {
  left: 425px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid18 {
  left: 475px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid19 {
  left: 500px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid20 {
  left: 525px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid21 {
  left: 550px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid22 {
  left: 575px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid23 {
  left: 600px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid24 {
  left: 625px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid25 {
  left: 650px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid26 {
  left: 675px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid27 {
  left: 700px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid28 {
  left: 725px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid29 {
  left: 750px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid30 {
  left: 775px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid31 {
  left: 800px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid32 {
  left: 825px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid33 {
  left: 850px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid34 {
  left: 875px;
  width: 1px;
  height: 465px;
  top: 20px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid35 {
  top: 25px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid36 {
  top: 50px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid37 {
  top: 75px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid38 {
  top: 100px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid39 {
  top: 125px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid40 {
  top: 150px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid41 {
  top: 175px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid42 {
  top: 200px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid43 {
  top: 225px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid44 {
  top: 275px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid45 {
  top: 300px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid46 {
  top: 325px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid47 {
  top: 350px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid48 {
  top: 375px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid49 {
  top: 400px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid50 {
  top: 425px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid51 {
  top: 450px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #94a6ab;
  position: absolute;
}

#grid52 {
  top: 475px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #bfd8e0;
  position: absolute;
}

#zero {
  position: absolute;
  top: 255px;
  left: 440px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: Optima;
  color: #78d69e;
}

#text1 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 10px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid green;
  z-index: 2;
}

#text2 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 10px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid green;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}

#text3 {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: 10px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid green;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}

#point1 {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  z-index: 3;
}

#point2 {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  z-index: 3;
}

#point3 {
  width: 11px;
  height: 11px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  z-index: 3;
}

#line1 {
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
}

#line2 {
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  z-index: 1;
}

#line3 {
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  transform-origin: left;
  z-index: 1;
}

#sine {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#cosine {
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#hypotenuse {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
}

#inputX1 {
  left: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#inputY1 {
  left: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#inputX2 {
  left: 340px;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#inputY2 {
  left: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="display">
    <div id="input">
      <p id="inputX1">Point A - X: <input id="inputX1-1" type="text"></p>
      <p id="inputY1">Point A - Y: <input id="inputY1-2"></p>
      <p id="inputX2">Point B - X: <input id="inputX2-3"></p>
      <p id="inputY2">Point B - Y: <input id="inputY2-4"></p>
      <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p id="gridX"></p>
      <p id="gridY"></p>
      <p id="grid1"></p>
      <p id="grid2"></p>
      <p id="grid3"></p>
      <p id="grid4"></p>
      <p id="grid5"></p>
      <p id="grid6"></p>
      <p id="grid7"></p>
      <p id="grid8"></p>
      <p id="grid9"></p>
      <p id="grid10"></p>
      <p id="grid11"></p>
      <p id="grid12"></p>
      <p id="grid13"></p>
      <p id="grid14"></p>
      <p id="grid15"></p>
      <p id="grid16"></p>
      <p id="grid17"></p>
      <p id="grid18"></p>
      <p id="grid19"></p>
      <p id="grid20"></p>
      <p id="grid21"></p>
      <p id="grid22"></p>
      <p id="grid23"></p>
      <p id="grid24"></p>
      <p id="grid25"></p>
      <p id="grid26"></p>
      <p id="grid27"></p>
      <p id="grid28"></p>
      <p id="grid29"></p>
      <p id="grid30"></p>
      <p id="grid31"></p>
      <p id="grid32"></p>
      <p id="grid33"></p>
      <p id="grid34"></p>
      <p id="grid35"></p>
      <p id="grid36"></p>
      <p id="grid37"></p>
      <p id="grid38"></p>
      <p id="grid39"></p>
      <p id="grid40"></p>
      <p id="grid41"></p>
      <p id="grid42"></p>
      <p id="grid43"></p>
      <p id="grid44"></p>
      <p id="grid45"></p>
      <p id="grid46"></p>
      <p id="grid47"></p>
      <p id="grid48"></p>
      <p id="grid49"></p>
      <p id="grid50"></p>
      <p id="grid51"></p>
      <p id="grid52"></p>
      <p id="zero">0</p>
    </div>
    <div id="drag1">
      <div id="point1"></div>
      <div id="text1"></div>
      <div id="line1">
        <div id="cosine"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="drag2">
      <div id="point2"></div>
      <div id="text2"></div>
      <div id="line2">
        <div id="sine"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="drag3">
      <div id="point3"></div>
      <div id="text3"></div>
      <div id="line3"></div>
      <div id="hypotenuse"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gewerh/3g47ujtq/

Comment: set the `position` of the elements and parent?

Comment: Did you add the `position` attribute?  `top` and `left` only work on positioned elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set the CSS position attribute:

> The effect of top depends on how the element is positioned (i.e., the
>   value of the position property):
>
> - When position is set to absolute or fixed, the top property specifies    the distance between the element's top edge and the top
>     edge of its    containing block. (Containing block needs to have
>     property position:    relative)
> - When position is set to relative, the top property    specifies the distance the element's top edge is moved below its    normal position.
> - When position is set to sticky, the top property    behaves like its position is relative when the element is inside the    viewport,
>     and like its position is fixed when it is outside.
> - When position is set to static, the top property has no effect.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top)

Comment: Adding the position to the new css works. I had the position set on the parent css assuming it would apply to the new div. I was wrong.

Thanks!